How hard is it to pull 1/0 feeder through 1-1/2 conduit?
My main panel is in an outbuilding and the subpanel (200A rated) in my house (built 30 years ago) is fed with 6AWG copper protected with a 60A breaker. I'd like to upgrade my home appliances from propane to electric (induction oven/range, dryer, water heater, heat pump), so I need more power. Obviously I could run dedicated underground service from the main panel to the outdoor appliances (heat pump, maybe a hot tub some day) but I'd prefer to make the most of the existing infrastructure so I'm thinking I should aim big.
The conduit from the outbuilding to the house is 107 ft of 1-1/2" sched 40 conduit with an LB on each end where the conduit comes up to the outside of the building. I dug up the elbow below the LB on one end and it's a standard 10"-ish radius elbow, and I assume it's the same on the other end. It's not exactly a straight shot, so there might be a couple 45s in there as well. Code would allow 2/0,2/0,2/0,4AWG for hot/hot/neutral/ground through 1-1/2" conduit, but I've read that's a really hard pull. 1/0 copper for hots/neutral would give me 150A and 1AWG copper would give me 125A. I'm happy to buy the proper mule tape and wire lube, and I have plenty of lever hoists/come alongs/winches/pulleys for mechanical advantage and equipment for rigging a pull point at the right angle. How crazy hard is it going to be to pull 1/0 copper through this conduit? Should I stick with 1AWG?
And yes, I know that aluminum would be much cheaper, and that 2" conduit would make my life much easier, but I don't want to tear up the landscaping between the outbuilding and my house.

There's an Android app called "Pullcalc" and if I feed in your data it says 76lb of force is needed, which sounds very low and I don't believe it but it wouldn't kill you to play with it.  I'd be interested in how close the app comes to the voice of actual experience you'll (hopefully) get here.  (I did 3x1/0, 1x#4, 3.8cm ID, PVC, XLPE, 170ft, 260 degrees, no rise).

"really hard"  could mean "leaves the aveage guy exhausted"  or "needs second tier power machinery" depending on who you ask, given Jay's comment I suspect it's the forner.

With enough leverage it will be easy.

There's a Technology Connections for electrifying houses on limited service capacoty.  Two in fact. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVLLNjSLJTQ
